# The better way to build a component displaying the states of multiple devices using React

Tags: reactjs, web-component, endpoint

Suppose I need to make a component (using **React**) that displays a devices state table that displays various device attributes such as their IP address, name, etc. Polling each device takes a few seconds, so you need to display a loading indicator for each specific device in the table.

I have several ways to make a similar component:

1. On the server side, I can create an API endpoint (like GET /device_info) that returns data for only one requested device and make **multiple parallel requests** from fontend to that endpoint for each device.
2. I can create an API endpoint (like GET /devices_info) that returns data for the entire list of devices at once on the server and make **one request** to it at once for the entire list of devices from frontend.

Each method has its pros and cons:

1. Way one:

   - Prons:

     - Easy to make. We make a "table row" component that requests data only for the device whose data it displays. The "device table" component will consist of several "table row" components that execute multiple queries in parallel each for their own device. This is especially true if you are using libraries such as **React Query** or **RTK Query** which support this behavior out of the box;
   - Cons:

     - Many requests to the endpoint, possibly hundreds (although the number of parallel requests can be limited);
     - If, for some reason, synchronization of access to some shared resource on the server side is required and the server supports several workers, then synchronization between workers can be very difficult to achieve, especially if each worker is a separate process;
2. Way two:

   - Prons:

     - One request to the endpoint;
     - There are no problems with access to some shared resource, everything is controlled within a single request on the server (because guaranteed there will be one worker for the request on the server side);
   - Cons:

     - It's hard to make. Since one request essentially has several intermediate states, since polling different devices takes different times, you need to make periodic requests from the UI to get an updated state, and you also need to support an interface that will support several states for each device such as: "not pulled", "in progress", "done";

With this in mind, my questions are:

1. What is the better way to make described component?
2. Does the better way have a name? Maybe it's some kind of pattern?
3. Maybe you know a great book/article/post that describes a solution to a similar problem?

Comment: I think what application it is matters the most when you consider such structures. Are you building an admin panel or an application for users? And by saying device data, do you mean your clients' devices information? It would be great if you could give more information about the component or project.

Answer (score 1):

> that displays a devices state

The component ***asking*** for a device state is so... 2010?

If your device knows its state, then have your device ***send*** its state to the component

**SSE** - Server Sent Events, and the EventSource API

- [https://developer.mozilla.org/.../API/Server-sent_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events)
- [https://developer.mozilla.org/.../API/EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)

[image]

PS. React is your choice; I would go Native JavaScript Web Components, so you have ZERO dependencies on Frameworks or Libraries for the next 30 JavaScript years

[image]

Many moons ago, I created a dashboard with PHP backend and Web Components front-end WITHOUT SSE: https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/ITpings
(no longer maintained)